# Representation theory terminology question

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, terminology, noncommutative-rings

For a paper I'm writing, I need a term for a representation-theoretic concept that I'm sure someone has thought of before, so I thought I'd ask here rather than just make something up.

Let $G$ be a group and $R$ be a commutative ring.  Consider an $R[G]$-module $V$.  For any ideal $I$ of $R$, we have the submodule
$$I V = \{\text{$c \cdot v$ $|$ $c \in I$ and $v \in V$}\}.$$
What is the term for $R[G]$-modules $V$ such that all submodules are of this form?  The ones I'm interested in have the additional property that if you ignore the $G$-action, then they are free $R$-modules (though not finitely generated!), but I doubt this matters for this question.

For an easy example, if $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $G = \text{GL}(n,\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}})$, then $\mathbb{Z}^n$ has this property.

If $R$ is a field, then this reduces the the usual notion of an irreducible representation, so I think of this as a version of irreducibility.  But looking through my ring-theory books, I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I guess being a group ring is not relevant here and you just want R-algebras A and an A- Module V (possibly required to be free over R) st the only submodules are the obvious ones coming from ideals of R.  I've Not seen a name

Comment: These are named and studied in https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82015258.pdf in the case G is trivial

Comment: Name of @BenjaminSteinberg's [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389525/representation-theory-terminology-question#comment992221_389525):  [Barnard - Multiplication modules](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(81)90112-5).